# 'No generic method 'GroupBy' on type 'System.Linq.Queryable' is compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to dynamically use reflection to do a GroupBy after a SelectMany:

```
var origType = typeof(CustomerCases);     
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(origType, "x");
var propExpr = Expression.Property(par, "Customer");
var firstGenType = typeof(Customer);
var resultType = typeof(IGrouping<,>).MakeGenericType(new [] {firstGenType, origType});

var lambda = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Convert(propExpr, resultType), parameter);

var groupbyExpression = Expression.Call(
                typeof(Queryable), 
                nameof(Queryable.GroupBy), 
                new [] { origType, firstGenType },
                querySelectMany.Expression, 
                lambda);
```

However, when trying to set the groupbyExpression, it throws an exception:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Linq.Expressions.dll but was not handled in user code: 'No generic method 'GroupBy' on type 'System.Linq.Queryable' is compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments. No type arguments should be provided if the method is non-generic. '

Any ideas?

Comment: What is type of `querySelectMany.Expression`? and your `lambda` looks a little bit strange to me.

Comment: I have ideas, but what you want to do with this grouping later? Select count, aggregation?

Comment: How can the result of your lambda be `IGrouping`? That is the result of a call to `GroupBy`.

Comment: Your code has other errors (e.g. `par` versus `parameter`). Please fix them.

Comment: why are you trying to create a generic group by? use a regular groupby - it is more maintenance friend. generic group by will be hazardous because they require evaluating the expression tree.

Comment: evaluating lambda expressions are slow.  I evaluated string expressions and they were slow to execute because the precompiler must compile the syntax at run time.